# How to access a field from multiple list in thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I am beginner in Thymeleaf, I have my class `Star` which has a list of another class called `Part`:

**Star class:**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idStar")
private List<Part> part;
```

and some other fields like

```
@Id
private Integer idStar;

@Column
private String soc;
```

**In Thymeleaf** I want to access data of `Star` class from template. This code is for the field `idStar`:

```
<tr th:each ="star : ${starList}">
    <td th:text="${star.idStar}"></td>
</tr>
```

but for the list of part I don't know how to access data, actually in `Part` class I've a field called `rep` which is also a list and in `Rep` class there is the field called `note` which I want to access.

**In Part class:**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idPart")
private List<Rep> rep;
```

**In Rep class:**

```
@Column
private Integer note;
```

I've done this code **but it doesn't work:**

```
<td th:text="${star.part.rep.note}"></td>
```

Could someone lead me to get `note` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `part` and `rep` fiels are lists, so expression like `${star.part.rep.note}` is meaningless. You could have zero or many **Part** objects inside the list so you must be specific from which one do you want to extract data. This also applies to list of **Rep** objects.

So if you want to get data from specific elements of those collections you have to use indexed access. E.g. get note from first Rep of first Part:

```
<td th:text="${star.part[0].rep[0].note}"></td>
```

On the other hand if you want to render all notes from all reps within star, you should use `th:each` like you do for `starList`:

```
<tr th:each ="star : ${starList}">
    <th:block th:each="p : ${star.part}">
                <td th:each="r : ${p.rep}" th:text="${r.note}"></td>
    </th:block>
</tr>
```

[th:block](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#synthetic-thblock-tag) used above doesn't render any element but was used for iterating parts reason.